# Arguments passed to the controller. Calling a method from another controller in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a form in *cshtml* file, at the bottom i have 2 buttons.

**Button 1** it calls its own method[HttpPost] in its own controller.

```
 <p>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitID" />
 </p>
```

**Button 2** I invoke the method "Add" in another controller, eg XYZ.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add btn", "Add", "XYZ",
           new { id = Model.myId }, "")
```

**Question:** How to call the action from the button 2 inside the controller (from button1)? Simply: Call method from another controller. 
And how to pass the *new { id = Model.myId }* to the controller.

Maybe there is a better method for this? Maybe what he wants to do it at odds with good practice? If so how should I get my results.

Comment: While syntactically possible, it's usually not the best way of solving this kind of problem. Would it be an acceptable solution for you to put that function in a different (static) class, so that every controller can directly call that class? This means the controllers can be changed independently, because if XYZ points to ABC, changing ABC will also influence XYZ (which you may miss)

Answer (score 1):

You might have to specify a little more, but assuming the action is `Add` and the Controller is `XYZ` you would do exactly what you're doing... Is there a problem?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I can't recall all the detail but within 1 controller method I used something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Method1(int id)
{
var controller = new XYZ();
return controller.Add(id);
}
```

You will need to add the above controller call to your current controller methods.

**UPDATE**
Perhaps a better solution is to have a common method that both controllers can call; this would be easier to maintain.

Comment: I've done this once or twice in the past, but it always later turned out to be a bad idea (generally). To be honest, I'm not sure you're using Controllers like you should. No offense intended, it's valid code and I've done this as well, but I don't see a use case where this is the best option. I could be wrong though, was hoping if anyone could shed some light on this?